# OfficeJs/WordJs select text range by index and bind click event

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, office-js

1. **First**, Using OfficeJS/WordJS how can I select text in a paragraph by index and length. For example, my paragraph has 100 characters and I need to select all from index 2 till index 16.
2. **Second**, When I found this range - how I can add an event handler for this range? I mean, when user click at 2-16 chars in my paragraph - I will show some useful information in my Add-in.

I'm using Word 2016 Add-in.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to explore the Range functionalities we added as part of the 1.3 update who is in preview right now. Please follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec) on how to try the preview.  please explore [the added Range object functionalities](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/range.md) (all whose Req set are 1.3 in the last column)

Please explore the "[split](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/range.md#splitdelimiters-string-multiparagraphs-bool-trimdelimiters-bool-trimspacing-bool)" functionality who enables you to split a paragraph into chunks of ranges when a set of delimiters is provided. For instance you can specify a space (" ") delimiter and get all the words in that paragraph. Check this example ([exercise 7 on the lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-docs/blob/master/O3652/O3652-2%20Deep%20Dive%20in%20Office%20Word%20Add-ins/Lab.md)) that splits a paragraph into words.

In conjunction with the split functionality, you can use [getRange](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/range.md#getrangerangelocation-string) and [expandTo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/range.md#expandtorange-range) methods to expand a range.  (so you get from index 'x' to 'y'

on your second question. Once you have the range, you can  wrap it with a titled content control  (range.insertContentControl and then specify a title for it), so that you can use the [Office.context.bindings.addToNamedItemAsync](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/bindings.addfromnameditemasync.md) API to create a Textbinding and subscribe [to the BindingSelected event](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/binding.bindingdatachangedevent.md), as shown on this example.

Hope this guides you in the right direction.