# How to select multiple paragraph from selection

Tags: typescript, office-js

I am developing a office js word addin.

Let's say I have three paragraphs in my word document. The user is selecting text from middle of 1st paragraph till middle of 2nd paragraph. When clicking a button in my addin the system should automatically select the text starting from 1st paragraph to till end of 2nd paragraph. The user should select the complete paragraph and not partial paragraphs. If they do the system should automatically select the whole paragraphs.

I need to know whether we have an option to redefine a range in officejs or any other way to achieve my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting question. You can make this work if you use the paragraphs collection of a range, on this case the currently selected range. The paragraphs collection (and in general all collections in the Word js API)  includes the full paragraph, not only what's selected.

Please run this example you will see how the full paragraphs are printed out of a partial selection (as described on your question)

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
        // this will return the full paragraphs within the selection:
        var myParagraphs = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
        context.load(myParagraphs);

        return context.sync()

        .then(function(){
            for(var i=0; i< myParagraphs.items.length; i++){
                // here you will get the full paragraphs, not just what the user selected.
                console.log("this is full  paragraph:" + (i + 1) + ":" + myParagraphs.items[i].text);

            }
        })
    });
```

Here is an example of how can you select the 2 paragraphs using expandTo and select...

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var pars = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
    pars.load();

    return context.sync().then(function () {
    pars.items[0].getRange().expandTo(pars.items[pars.items.length - 1].getRange()).select(); 
     
      return context.sync()

    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
})
```

Hope this sets you in the right path!
-Juan,

Comment: I need to know how we can select both the paragraphs in my scenario posted above. In Interop we can redefine the range and select it. I am not sure whether there is a way to achieve that in OfficeJS  

**Edit:** I have noticed you have suggested to use expandTo method in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279377. Can you tell me how we can expand the range in my scenario (the user is selecting partial paragraphs [starting from middle of 1st para to middle of 2nd para] and programmatically I need to select whole paragraph)?

Comment: You can get the range of each paragraph using paragraph.getRange() then you can expand it using range.expandTo() and lastly once you expanded the ranges you can use range.Select()

Comment: Thats what I also thought and here is the code I have so far. 
https://jsfiddle.net/bkuzmdsb/#&togetherjs=7uFHoTVdw5

Comment: I am getting error on below statement:
var firstSelectedParaRange = pars.items[0].getRange('Whole');

Comment: interesting... i just added more detail to my original answer a bit to show you how can you select the paragraphs. basically once you have loaded the paragraph collection it can be simplified to 1 line of code:       pars.items[0].getRange().expandTo(pars.items[pars.items.length - 1].getRange()).select();

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code and I was getting error as "Property 'select' does not exist on type void". Then I have modified the code as 

`var modifiedPara = pars.items[0].getRange();`
`modifiedPara.expandTo(pars.items[pars.items.length - 1].getRange());`
`modifiedPara.select();`

Now I am getting error as "Object doesn't support property or method 'getRange'".

Comment: My original code must work. Please send me your office build and also what office.js CDN are you using?

Comment: Deferred Channel; Version: 16.0.6965.2105; 
Office.js from Nuget version 1.1.0.9 and also tried 1.1.0.10

Comment: Ok that explains it all. You are trying our preview APIs in a quite old build. Please make sure to follow the instructions here to install a fresh release and the beta cdn https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/README.md

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.